# Experience Optimization custom parameters or claims

Tags: dxa, ambient-data-framework, experience-optimization, dxa2.2

I have DXA 2.2 web application running with Experience Optimization and displaying the Promotions based on some basic Trigger Types like user browser etc. I am not using Audience Manager database instead web-application stores user data in application specific database. Now I wish to implement some custom Trigger Types like based on some column (for example age column) in user records stored in web-application custom database.

Can you please help me understand what needs to be done for writing custom triggers? Any pointers to any such documentation would be very helpful?

Comment: This is probably a good starting point: https://www.godigitalwithsayantan.com/post/simplest-way-to-create-custom-claim-in-dxa-with-net

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would check this.